# Filling colour between two concentric ovals

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am a newbie in iOS development. I have two bezier curves which are oval in shape.

```
UIBezierPath *bpath1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 40, 40)];

    UIBezierPath *bpath2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(x + 10, y + 10, 20, 20)];
```

I want to fill a colour between these to ovals. To get a white colour in the smaller oval I tried this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIBezierPath *bpath1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 40, 40)];

    UIBezierPath *bpath2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(x + 10, y + 10, 20, 20)];

    UIColor *fillColor1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0.5];
    UIColor *fillColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.2);

    CGContextAddPath(context, bpath1.CGPath);
    [fillColor1 setFill];
    [bpath1 fill];        

    CGContextAddPath(context, bpath2.CGPath);
    [fillColor2 setFill];
    [bpath2 fill];
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

But the colour of outer circle gets filled in the inner one. Is there any way to only fill the path between these two ovals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to fill the smaller oval with a white colour, change your fillColor2 code to this:

```
UIColor *fillColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

or this:

```
UIColor *fillColor2 = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

The smaller circle is showing up black because filling red, green, and blue values with 0 results in black.